# 起動しているGAEインスタンスの数をリアルタイムで取得する方法はありますでしょうか？

Tags: google-app-engine

方法を見つけることができませんでした...
何か方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 5):

Google App Engine Admin API
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/

下記APIで起動しているinstanceのリストを取得できるので、それを数えればよいかと。
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions.instances/list
ただしServiceとVersionの指定が必要です。

Answer (score 2):

何のためにインスタンス数が知りたいのかが、分からないので、最適な解は分かりませんが、いくつか方法があります。

1. Stackdriverのmetricを参照する
   https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list を使って `appengine.googleapis.com/system/instance_count` を参照します
   [Example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/monitoring.projects.timeseries.list/m/monitoring/v3/monitoring.projects.timeSeries.list?name=projects%252Fgcp-ug&filter=metric.type+%253D+%2522appengine.googleapis.com%252Fsystem%252Finstance_count%2522&interval.endTime=2016-12-02T15%253A01%253A23.045123456Z&interval.startTime=2016-12-02T10%253A01%253A23.045123456Z&_h=5&)
2. App Engineのログを [Cloud Pub/SubにExport](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export) して、ログからInstance IDを抜き出す
   Pub/SubのログをCloud DataflowやApp Engine, Compute Engineなどでひたすら処理する必要があります。